# which is best for the client performance

Tags: performance

Which is better, small data size and more server requests, or large data size  and fewer requests? Larger data size means longer processing time on ther server. How does this scale out thouh as the number of users and their activity increases?

Comment: Measure it. But, in general, *throughput* increases as connection overhead decreases. On the flip side, larger payloads can also increase *response times* (even if the requests are ultimately more efficient overall). Of course, there are other factors in play. Fewer larger requests/responses (e.g. a refined API) can lead to more efficient database queries, for instance.

Comment: Very hard to answer the question without some more detail e.g. what sort of latency are we talking about here - browser to HTTP server, or app server to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always ideal to get all that you need in as many less calls as you can. If you can get all that you need in one call, definitely do it.

Also it will be very helpful if you can give some insight of what kind of application are we talking about here.

Comment: A forum. I would have figured that smaller size meant less stress on server for processing, and quicker page load time for the client.

Comment: smaller requests doesnt guarantee quick response time. If there are too many small requests on server, your response time will decrease. You need to balance your on-demand calls keeping in mind that you only load that data initially that is good for at least 75% of users.